# Size of EF context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My app uses Entity Framework. As I perform operations on the Context, such as inserts/deletes/updates, due to its unity of work behavior im sure it occupies more and more memory as these operations take place.

My question here is: Is there a way to obtain how much memory is the context holding in a given moment?

Details:

- No Lazy Loading being used
- No Proxy Creation
- EF 4

Comment: Pretty sure EF wasn't built with a way to provide this information.  You could probably figure it out, but it would not be very easy at all.

Comment: The DbContext should be as short lived as possible. Instantiate -> Execute SQL query -> Dispose. This way you shouldn't be worried about memory consumption. Obviously it would also depend on what you are doing with the hydrated entities but that's no longer related to EF.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I agree but in this case, lots and lots of entities are altered...

Comment: Alright, but this has nothing to do with EF. It's a more general problem. You might consider working in batches or some other algorithm. It would obviously very much depend on the specific problem you are trying to solve. It would be hard to help without more context on the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to monitorize memory and CPU usage of objects within an application or service is a synonym of requiring a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).

There're many options here. It's just about looking for [".NET profiler"](https://www.google.es/search?q=%22.NET%20profiler%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=n-CmVPryOcKuUcnXgtgL#q=.NET%20profiler) in Google.

*Note I'm redirecting you to Google to avoid spam.*

Answering to @Servy's concern:

> Profilers are fine for a debugging tool during development. It's not
>   really something that you can use during the execution of the program
>   outside of development. I get the impression that that's what he's
>   asking about. –

It's when the requirement of implementing some kind of load tests arises. OP should implement some test cases which mimic real-world scenarios to get stats as close as possible to actual production execution of the same code.

Comment: Profilers are fine for a debugging tool during development.  It's not really something that you can use during the execution of the program outside of development.  I get the impression that that's what he's asking about.

Comment: @Servy Servy Servy, you know you're about to open the hell :D